# How to protect my 555 timer against DC motor noise?

Tags: dc-motor, noise, 555, npn

I have this circuit:

[image]

(Sorry for such a bad schematic.)

As you can see, there is a DC motor that gets power from 12V source, using a NPN transistor controlled by a 0-5V signal.

Please note that there is no 'direct link' between the 555 timer and the circuit for the DC motor.

However when POS_1 or POS_2 are active, the DC motor starts to run and the output signal ('CLK') of the 555 stops working, i.e., the LEDs that are suposed to blink with 1Hz frequency stop blinking. Actually, they start blinking at a very high frequency, I imagine that is noise which is filtering through the 12V source (which is also supplying the regulator that supplies the 555 chip.)

I'm sorry but I don't have an oscilloscope to prove this.

I've tried this:

- To put a huge electrolytic capacitor (220uF) and a ceramic (1uF for high frequencies) between 5V and GND on 555.
- To replace the 12V supply of the DC motor with 5V for a lower consumption.
- To add in parallel to the motor a ceramic capacitor (100nF) to smooth its curve.
- To change the resistors and capacitor of the 555 that are involved in the calculations of frequency, in order to avoid noise passing through the capacitor.

And other many little tests that I'm not able to remember at this moment.

What can I do to protect my 555 from the DC motor noise?

Comment: Did you decouple all your ICs? The power-gnd pins of every IC should have a ceramic cap as close as possible to the pins. 100nF is a rule of thumb.

Comment: Yes, I tried. But still happening... P.S.: @JRE thank you for editing and please sorry for my english! It's not my mother tongue...

Comment: Add another regulator to power the 555. If necessary, add a diode and BFC (large capacitor to isolate the input voltage to the regulator). But if your supply voltage is dropping your best bet is a more capable power supply or a smaller motor.

Comment: Measure the 12V while the motor is running.  It **must** stay above 8V for the 7805 to regulate properly.  If that is OK, then measure the 5V output.  It should stay at 5V while the motor is running.  If it goes down (or up!) while the motor is running, then you've got noise  getting through the regulator.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I also tried to test with an independent source (a 230VAC to 5DC transformer) to separate sources, but it still happened. Both grounds were the same so that's another reason for me to think that it's about noise... Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @JRE OK, I've just tried and the voltages barely change (11.99V -> 11.87V and 4.99V -> 4.84V).

Comment: measure the 5V whilethe motor is running, with that capacitor on pin 5 of the 555 it should be immune to noise.

Comment: that 40mA on the bottom relay can't be right.

Comment: That's a 150 millivolt change in the output from the 555.  That shouldn't happen.  There's noise getting through.

Comment: What is your 12V source?  Is it a powersupply, or is it a battery?

Comment: @Jasen measured: 4.64V. About the 40 mA... what do you mean? I can't find it. Maybe you are refering to the 10mA that runs through the relay? Value on it doesn't matter... I mean, that is a wrong calculation. But forget that relay. It's out at this moment because it's wrong. The rest of the schematic it's the same.

Comment: @JRE It's a powersupply (max 1.5A)

Comment: near `(6)`  "40" might actually be AO or "10"  but there's only 4.4mA available.

Comment: @Jasen yes, that's what I was meaning to. That's 10 mA. But just ignore them (the red texts), they're theoretycall calculations

Comment: 4.64V - somethings wrong. maybe your 12V  supply isn't strong enough.

Comment: It should. My entire circuit is consuming 200 mA (with the DC motor working under 5V)

Comment: figure out what's wrong with the 5v supply, could be the regulator overheating.

Comment: @Jasen when I run the DC motor the regulator starts to warm up, but I'm not sure if it's normal. Putting on the finger, in less than 5 seconds you can feel the increase of temperature (touching the back plate).

Comment: It would be a good idea to use a 5V zener diode in order to keep the voltage? What do you think? Thank you!